# Log4J; how to ensure timestamps are always in GMT using ConversionPattern?

Tags: log4j, timestamp, gmt

How can I ensure that all timestamps that my log4j is using, are in GMT?

I have tried the following but it prints "GMT" inside the timestamp

```
log4j.appender.ConversionPattern=%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS}{GMT} %-4r %-5p [%t] %3x - %m%n
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have log4j-1.2.16 and the following lines work properly:

```
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}{GMT} [%-5p] [%t] [%F:%L] - %m%n
```

If it doesn't work, then you have to download extras (companios section).
This package contains EnhancedPatternLayout:
[Download apache-log4j-extras](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/download.html)

Comment: That didn't quite work for me even using log4j-1.2.17. Instead, I had to provide the explicit format string for ISO8601: %d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX}{GMT}

Comment: @asieira: Since log4j 1.2.16, `EnhancedPatternLayout` from log4j-extras is included in the standard log4j 1 distribution ([changelog](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/changes-report.html#a1.2.16), [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48927)), and the time zone specification works as given in this answer. If it didn't work in your case, I can only assume a botched distribution or config.