# log4j UTC datetime configuration

Tags: java, log4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Log4J; how to ensure timestamps are always in GMT using ConversionPattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634585/log4j-how-to-ensure-timestamps-are-always-in-gmt-using-conversionpattern)

How do i configure the log4j to display the datetime in UTC format.

At the moment i am using the below configuration

```
<appender name="trap-appender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="logs/exception/ExceptionLog.log" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS}:%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634585/log4j-how-to-ensure-timestamps-are-always-in-gmt-using-conversionpattern and apply UTC instead of GMT if you wish.

Comment: It worked for me when i used the EnhancedPatternLayout present in log4j-extras (version i used 1.1)<layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS}{UTC}:%m%n" />
  </layout>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way. But one way to crack this nut is to extend `PatternLayout`:

1. write your own DateFormat, similar to log4j's `AbsoluteTimeDateFormat`.
2. extend `PatternParser` and override `void finalizeConverter(char c)` to support a new special formatting code, for example `%d{UTC}`.
3. extend `PatternLayout` and override `createPatternParser` to return your sub class of `PatternParser`.
4. change your configuration to use your sub class of `PatternLayout`.

Comment: While what I wrote will work, the duplicate mentioned by @Kal is a far superior solution.